# Heap size calculations

Tags: apex

Which is the best one to use considering Heap size and CPU time and also explain me about heap size calculation

Approach 1

```
for(List<Lead> leadlist :[SELECT id FROM Lead]){

    for(Lead leadobj:leadlist){

     //code here
    }
}
```

Approach 2:

```
for(Lead leadObj :[SELECT id FROM Lead]){
    // code here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [SOQL For Loops](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm).

**About heap size:**

> SOQL for loops retrieve all sObjects, using efficient chunking with calls to the query and queryMore methods of the SOAP API. Developers should always use a SOQL for loop to process query results that return many records, to avoid the limit on [heap size](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm#total_heap_size_limit_desc).

**About single record vs. list:**

> ### SOQL For Loop Formats
>
> SOQL for loops can process records one at a time using a single sObject variable, or in batches of 200 sObjects at a time using an sObject list:
>
> - The single sObject format executes the for loop's  once per sObject record. Consequently, it is easy to understand and use, but is grossly inefficient if you want to use data manipulation language (DML) statements within the for loop body. Each DML statement ends up processing only one sObject at a time.
> - The sObject list format executes the for loop's  once per list of 200 sObjects. Consequently, it is a little more difficult to understand and use, but is the optimal choice if you need to use DML statements within the for loop body. Each DML statement can bulk process a list of sObjects at a time.